# Win32: How do I make an HWND transparent to clicks?

Tags: winapi, hwnd

I want an HWND that is transparent to clicks (i.e. passes them through to windows underneath).

At first I tried WS_EX_TRANSPARENT but that has all sorts of redraw problems. Windows underneath end up drawing over my HWND.

I did some searching and found a suggestion to respond to WM_NCHITTEST by returning HTTRANSPARENT. This seemed to work but MSDN states that it only works correctly when the windows underneath are in the same thread. Searching for HTTTRANSPARENT turned up some problems (http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=147)

So...any other ideas?

Comment: I've never had a problem using WM_NCHITTEST.  Does your application create windows in different threads?

Comment: Yes, this is part of a Ui library that is specifically designed to handle being called from many threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch all mouse messages and forward them to the underlying window with PostMessage.

Comment: Sounds great except...how do you find the window underneath? That works for all processes?

Comment: You'll have to enumerate all top level windows using GetWindow (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515(VS.85).aspx) and check their positions. When you find one, you'll then use ChildWindowFromPoint (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: That is an incredibly naive approach which isn't going to work out in practice. A `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` message, for example, may not be over the non-client area of the window underneath, so blindly passing the message along isn't sufficient. There are also *loads* of internal state being recorded during input processing, which isn't when posting fake messages (see [`SetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) to imaging how this is going to break). This is not a tractable solution.